# View receives touch events when covered by other view

Tags: java, android

My Android app has a layout that looks like this:

```
---------------------
|                   |
|      button       |  <- View panel A
|                   |
---------------------
|                   |
|                   |  <- view panel B (a SurfaceView)
|                   |
|-------------------|
```

I use a relative layout so that panel B fills the whole screen and panel A is at the top of the screen covering the top of panel B. A is slightly transparent so you can see B under it.
Pressing the button on panel A works as expected.

My problem: **if I press anywhere on panel A outside of the button, panel B receives a touch event. How can I stop this behaviour?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a clickListener and attach it to Panel A and dont do anything in that clickListener

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The solution seems so obvious now. I guess I thought the default behaviour was weird but, now that I think about it, views are transparent by default so you'd usually want the click to go through.

Comment: Found a simpler way: set the "clickable" XML attribute to true.